# What is this for-loop doing and can write it differently?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I just found this piece of code in a software project I'm interested in and I don't quite understand what this for-loop is doing:

`for (; *szMask; ++szMask, ++pData, ++bMask)`

This are the definitions of the used variables:

`const BYTE* pData, const BYTE* bMask, const char* szMask`

Can you please explain me what this loop does and if there are other ways I can write this for-loop with the same result?

Comment: This loop is equivalent to while(*szMask){++szMask, ++pData,++bMask}

Comment: I can kind of understand the downvotes, but can someone explain what you're supposed to do if you have this question?

Comment: @Untitled123 You sit down with a pen and paper and walk through the instructions one by one.

Comment: but if we look at questions that can be figured out with walking through instructions, that would be a far more sizeable portion..

Comment: @user4581301 But I don't even know what I'd do with with pen & paper because I don't know what for-statement exactly do. stackoverflow gets more and more poor.

Comment: You look up the documentation. Why do you expect us to explain everything about that code? At least explain the parts you *do* understand.

Comment: I feel like the majority of people would go on stack overflow/google instead of looking up c++ documentation.  On the same reasoning, for(;;) is also another one that doesn't make much sense initially.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (; *szMask; ++szMask, ++pData, ++bMask)
{
    /* other stuff */
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
while(*szMask)
{
    /* other stuff */
    ++szMask, ++pData, ++bMask;
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
while(*szMask)
{
    /* other stuff */
    ++szMask;
    ++pData;
    ++bMask;
}
```

This is all that can be inferred from your question, so hopefully you can figure out what this while loop does.

Comment: I think that people vote down everything related to this question.

Comment: It makes people just not answer bad questions, even if they're willing to help out...

Comment: Not sure if that's a bad thing.

Comment: @Untitled123 While _@immibis_ certainly isn't a super new user, the assumptions made from the answer are going to far to give a certain reasoning and predict what's the output finally.

Comment: To be honest, this is about as good an answer as you can give a question like this. It answers what's possible to be answered and leaves a caveat that it couldn't answer everything.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was referring more to the question asker haha